# Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: class, find, program-entry-point

I have created a Project `Blah` in Eclipse. Under `Blah` I have a package called say `mooshu`

Inside this package I have three unrelated java classes, Tut1, Tut2, Tut3 each with their own main method. All three classes have compiled fine (unrelated).

Now when I open Tut2 and try to run it within eclipse, I am getting this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class mooshu

What gives?

[no need for code] any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Although the question asked is very old, but I am answering this, considering the fact, if any one is facing the same problem. You cannot have multiple main methods under your single package. Only one class can have a main method which will be responsible of calling other methods of different classes(If necessary).